# Plot_cap response curve for counterfactual data

Tags: r, plot, regression, predict, marginal-effects

The following code was made up to replicate my problem with a bigger, more complex data set.

```
library(marginaleffects)
library(truncnorm)

yield_kgha<-rtruncnorm(n=100, mean=2000, sd=150)
n_kgha<-rtruncnorm(n=100, a=40, b=298, mean=150, sd=40)

i<-lm(yield_kgha~n_kgha+I(n_kgha^2))
summary(i)
```

I have used the `predictions` function from the `marginaleffects` package to see the predicted yields(`yield_kgha`) for a range of nitrogen rates (`n_kgha`) from my regression model (`i`). My original data only has n_kgha rates ranging from approximately 40-250, so the below code allows me to see predicted yields at n_kgha rates not actually in my data set.

```
p <- predictions(
  i,
  newdata = datagrid(model = i, n_kgha = seq(0, 300, by = 25), grid_type = "counterfactual"))
summary(p, by = "n_kgha")
```

I would like to plot the response of yield conditioned on n_kgha ranging from 0-300, which includes n_kgha values not in my original data set. I have tried to do this using the `plot_cap` function.

plot_cap(i, condition = "n_kgha")

However, since my original data only has n_kgha rates ranging from 40-250 I am not getting my desired result of seeing the response curve over the n_kgha (0:300) range. When I plot using the plot_cap function I get the following response curve with `n_kgha` ranging from 40-250 (the max and min of the original data set).

[image]

Is there a way to run the `plot_cap` function based on the counterfactual range of n_kgha as used in the `predictions` function? Or should I use another method to plot the predicted values based on counterfactual values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot_cap()` function only plots over the observed range of values. However, since `predictions()` returns a “tidy” data frame, it is trivial to use the the output of this function with `ggplot2` to get the plot you need.

Note that we do *not* need to specify `grid.type="counterfactual"`. This is option will do something very weird and specific: duplicate the whole dataset many times for each value of the user-supplied values. It is only useful in very specific corner-cases, and *not* when you just want to make predictions over unobserved values of the predictors. See the documentation with `?datagrid`.

Here’s a simple example of `predictions()` with `ggplot2` to achieve what you want:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(truncnorm)
library(ggplot2)

yield_kgha <- rtruncnorm(n = 100, mean = 2000, sd = 150)
n_kgha <- rtruncnorm(n = 100, a = 40, b = 298, mean = 150, sd = 40)

i <- lm(yield_kgha ~ n_kgha + I(n_kgha^2))

p <- predictions(i, newdata = datagrid(n_kgha = seq(0, 300, 10)))

ggplot(p, aes(n_kgha, predicted)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = .1) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]